# Groupby sum of col1 divided by sum of col2

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have DF like this:

[image]

and I want to calculate how much is students was prepared via his overall score in the exam, like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

**Edit:**
the answer given by @user17242583 is right, but, the values are stacked in the first rows, how to implement each value to each needed row ?
[image]

Comment: If you read the wiki page for the pandas (stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info), you'll see a link to a question "How to make good reproducible pandas examples".

Comment: Thanks i will look at it, i tried to find similar problem but all i found was how to groupby 1 column or two but without any further operation @PaulH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
s = df.groupby(['Student', 'Exam']).apply(lambda group: (f'{group["IsCorrect"].sum()}\\{group.shape[0]}', (group['IsCorrect'].sum() / group.shape[0]))).reset_index(drop=True)
df['prepared'] = s.str[0]
df['prepared percentage'] = s.str[1]
```

Comment: yes thank you that's half the answer, the values are stacked in the first rows, how to implement each value to each needed row ?